# Batch file to: move files into a sub folder if they contain the filename of another file

Tags: search, batch-file, filenames, move

This code works well for me to move files with the same filename but different extension into a subfolder.

So the current logic is: *If an NC1 file has the same filename as a PDF file then move that NC1 to its respective subfolder.*

But my files don't have the same filename.

The following are 2 example files:

- "**f100**.nc1"
- "999-P-**f100** - PLATE - Rev 0 - 287x200.pdf"

How do I change this code to follow this logic: *If a PDF filename CONTAINS the filename of an NC1 file then move that NC1 to its respective subfolder.*

```
    for %%j in ("..\2PDF_Outsourced\1PDF_Heavy\*.pdf") do (
        if exist "%%~nj.nc1" (
            move /-y "%%~nj.nc1" "\2NC1_Outsourced\1NC1_Heavy"
        )
    )

    for %%j in ("..\2PDF_Outsourced\1PDF_Light\*.pdf") do (
        if exist "%%~nj.nc1" (
            move /-y "%%~nj.nc1" "\2NC1_Outsourced\1NC1_Light"
        )
    )
```

Thank you in advance for any help. I have been stuck at this stage for a while and am struggling to understand delimiters, strings, and wildcards.

Comment: Thank you all for your swift responses. I will try them and respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to reverse your logic. Iterate the .nc1 files and then look to see if matching .pdf exists (with wildcards). Adding a 2nd loop for Heavy and Light avoids code replication.

```
for %%F in ("*.nc1") do for %%P in (Heavy Light) do (
  if exist "..\2PDF_Outsourced\1PDF_%%P\*%%~nF*.pdf" (
    if exist "%%F" move /-y "%%F" "\2NC1_Outsourced\1NC1_%%P"
  )
)
```

**EDIT**

I added a 2nd IF EXIST to the code above just in case the name matches both Heavy and Light pdf files.

If Endoro's concern about ignoring names that match a substring of a larger word is valid, then the above can be extended:

```
for %%F in ("*.nc1") do (
  set "name=%%~nF"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  for %%C in (. [ ^^) do set "name=!name:%%C=\%%C!"
  for %%N in (!name!) do (
    endlocal
    for %%P in (Heavy Light) do for /f "eol=: delims=" %%A in (
      'dir /b /a-d "..\2PDF_Outsourced\1PDF_%%P\*%%~nF*.pdf"^|findsdr /i "\<%%N\>"'
    ) do if exist "%%F" move /-y "%%F" "\2NC1_Outsourced\1NC1_%%P"
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you dbenham. I am using this code now. The first code above is suitable for me as there will never be the same string within another filename.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `findstr`:

```
REM this is true
echo(999-P-f100 - PLATE - Rev 0 - 287x200|findstr "\<f100\>"

REM this is false
echo(999-P-f1000 - PLATE - Rev 0 - 287x200|findstr "\<f100\>"

REM also false
echo(999-P-f10 - PLATE - Rev 0 - 287x200|findstr "\<f100\>"
```

you can put this in a `for` loop:

```
for %%i in (*.nc1) do (
    for /f "delims=" %%j in ('dir /a-d /b "..\2PDF_Outsourced\1PDF_Heavy\*.pdf"^|findstr /i "%%~ni"') do (
```

Comment: +1, Interesting cases that were not identified by the OP. Not sure if it is a real issue. The potential is there that file names containing regex meta characters `.`, `[`, or `^` would need to be escaped.

Comment: Thank you Endoro. I am still trying to make this work for me. But I am new to batch files and am struggling a bit. I am using another answer successfully. But I will continue to try to understand your technique for experience.

Answer (score 0):

not tested :

```
@echo off

call :copy_pdf "\2NC1_Outsourced\1NC1_Light"
call :copy_pdf "\2NC1_Outsourced\1NC1_Heavy"
goto :eof

:copy_pdf [%1 - directory to search]
if not exist "%~1\" echo dir not exist >2 & exit /b 1
pushd "..\%~1"
for %%N in (*.nc1) {
    for /f "delims=" %%P in ('dir /b /s /a:-d *.pdf^| find /i "%%~nN"') do (
        move /-y "%%~nP.nc1" "%~1" 
    ) 
)
popd
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a brute force approach that can help you get started

```
for %%a in ("*.nc1") do (
  for %%b in ("*.pdf") do (
    echo.%%~nb | findstr /i /c:"%%~na" 1>nul
    if not errorlevel 1 (
      echo %%~na found in %%~nb
    )  
  )
)
```

if you have many NC1 and PDF files then you may need to optimize this method (for example by storing the list of PDF files)